# What is the broken-sublattice-symmetry phase in an intermediate temperature of the three-state antiferromagnetic Potts model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

I have just read one paper ( [Phys. Rev. E 54, R5885 (1996)](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v54/i6/pR5885_1) )  where it was mentioned that the broken-sublattice-symmetry (BSS) phase was stable in the whole low-temperature region. The BSS phase at very low temperatures can be described by $p_{1,A}=1$, $p_{2,A}=p_{3,A}=0$, $p_{1,B}=0$, $p_{2,B}=p_{3,B}=1/2$, where $p_{k,α}$ is the probability that sublattice $α=A,B$ takes the $k$-th ($k=1,2,3$) Potts State.

But how could the BSS phase in an intermediate temperature (say, $T=1.2$) be discribed by the six $p_{k,α}$s ?

I have calculated numerically, and found that at $T=1.21$ ,   $p_{1A}=0.264,p_{2A}=0.2278,p_{3A} =0.5083;p_{1B} =0.3932,p_{2B}=0.4333,p_{3B} =0.1734$ . Is it in the BSS phase at this temperature?

Comment: For an intermediate temperature, finding the six $p_{k,\alpha}$ (1) is not an easy calculation, if it's doable at all, and (2) is not a sufficient description of the BSS phase, as there may be correlations between states at short distances. You could do it numerically by a simulation where you start at temperature 0 and slowly raise it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the probability you cited can only be achieved at exactly zero temperature. Think about that, if the temperature is not zero, there are always finite probability that the spin will be changed, which means that $p_{2,A}\ne0$, etc.

At very high temperature, the spin are completely random, so $p_{k,\alpha}=1/3$. The order parameter itself and the site spin average are continuous with temperature, so the probability should decrease to zero gradually and take a non-zero value at intermediate temperature. There is nothing special at $T=1.2$

Comment: Presumably, in the BSS phase $p_{2B}=p_{3B}$ and in the RS phase $P_{2B} > p_{3B}$. It's not clear that the BSS phase is stable (the symmetry might be spontaneously broken, and the BSS phase might turn into the RS phase).

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I always curious whether there are better ways to find answer other than simulations.

Comment: There may be more than one quasi-stable phase at a given temperature. This one looks like the description of the RS phase, since $2/3 > p_{3A} > p_{2B} > p_{1B} > 1/3 > p_{1A} > p_{2A} > p_{3B}$.

Comment: @hlew Are you getting the results from simulation? If yes, (1) Make sure you have sufficiently large sample. (2) You need to extrapolate your results to infinite lattice size with need some method of finite size scaling.

Comment: Run the simulation several times, and see what the distribution of $|p_{1A}-p_{2A}|$ look like. If it looks like a distribution peaked at 0, it's probably the BSS phase. If they look like a distribution peaked away from 0, it's probably not.

Comment: You could run the simulation for various temperatures. I suspect 1.2 might be right above the phase transition between BSS and RS, in which case you would expect $p_{1A}$ and $p_{2A}$ to be close.

Comment: @hlew From the Fig1 of the paper you cited. It seems there is transition at 0.7 and 1.3 (havent read in details). Why dont you try to plot $p_{ij}$ as temp, there might be discontinuity in first derivative.

Comment: @hlew I am not quite sure for the Potts model. But the order might change, and if it does, it should occur at a critical temperature (or near, for finite system) for phase change.